# how to make this code Non-Blocking with Asyncio?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, client, python-asyncio, nonblocking

I'm trying to create a code that is non-blocking and that allows me to create multiple clients to do some request on a server. However, I can't create more than 1 client simultaneously!

## CLIENT.PY

```
import asyncio

PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG = 1


#ECHO CLIENT PROTOCOL 

async def tcp_echo_client(message, loop):
    # Send request to server
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 8888, loop=loop)
    print('Send: %r' % message)
    writer.write(message.encode())

    # Receive the information
    if message == '1':
        await asyncio.Task(read_position(reader))
    else:
        await asyncio.ensure_future(read_server(reader))

    # Close the connection
    print('Close the socket')
    writer.close()


#ASYNCIO COROUTINES TO REQUEST INFORMATION 

async def read_server(reader):
    server_message = await reader.read()
    print(type(server_message))
    print('Received: %r' % server_message.decode())


async def read_position(reader):
    while True:
        print("I'm Here")
    
        server_message = await reader.read(50)
        position = server_message.split()
        print(position)
        print(type(position))
        print('Received: %r' % server_message.decode())


#FUNCTION THAT CREATES THE CLIENT


def main(message):
    '''This function creates the client'''

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(tcp_echo_client(message, loop))
    finally:
        pass


 # This is how I create a new client

if __name__ == '__main__':
    message = '2'
    main(message)
    message = '3'
    main(message)
```

I want to create multiples clients, however, the code is blocking in the first main when I send the message('1'). I don't know why the code is blocking if I'm using asyncio. My server accepts multiples connections, because if I run this code seperatly I can do everything. The propose of this is to create clients  every time I click a button at my Kivy app to send a request to the server.
This problems exists because I want to control a Robot and do a lot of things simultaneously, however with a blocking code I can't do it because I'm get stuck

Maybe it's a stupid question but I've only started coded 2 months ago and I haven't any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` function doesn't "create the client", as its docstring claims. It creates the client *and runs it to completion*. This is why multiple invocations of `main()` result in serial execution. `main()` being a regular function, that's exactly what you'd expect, asyncio doesn't change that. It's useful to remember that asyncio is single-threaded, so it can't do some "run in the background" magic, unless you cooperate.

To cooperate, you need to tell aysncio to start both clients, and then await them in parallel:

```
async def main(messages):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # launch the coroutines in parallel
    tasks = [loop.create_task(tcp_echo_client(msg, loop)) for msg in messages]
    # don't exit until all of them are done
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':        
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main(['2', '3']))
```

Note that when awaiting your coroutines, you don't need to wrap them in `asyncio.ensure_future()` or `asyncio.Task()` - asyncio will handle that automatically. `await read_position(reader)` and `await read_server(reader)` would work just fine and have the same meaning as the longer versions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However I still have a problem, because I have a GUI and i want to have the ability to create a client everytime I click on a button. For example, I have a button called Start Robot and another saying Stop Robot. When I start the robot I want to update the coordinates every second but I also need to have the ability to stop the robot. But I can't do it because the code will only allow me to create another client in the end of the previous one! That is the main Point here. Maybe it was me who didn't explain it well, sorry :(

Comment: @FilipeRibeiro This is indeed not clear from the question. If at all possible, you should include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you have a GUI, the right way to handle asyncio is to start a thread that runs the event loop, create a new event loop and run it there with [`loop.run_forever()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_forever). Then from your GUI you create new coroutines with [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe).